# Unable to download maven artifacts - connection reset

Tags: maven, jar, build, pom.xml, connection-reset

Every time I try to run a build when maven tries to download the artifacts it throws a `connection reset` error. I'm developing in Eclipse and am trying to use the embed-mongodb plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.joelittlejohn.embedmongo</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.13</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-embed-mongo</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-embed-mongo</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The build fails because it "could not transfer artifacts":

```
Failed to execute goal com.github.joelittlejohn.embedmongo:embedmongo-maven-plugin:0.1.13:start (start-embed-mongo) on project rest: Execution start-embed-mongo of goal com.github.joelittlejohn.embedmongo:embedmongo-maven-plugin:0.1.13:start failed: Plugin com.github.joelittlejohn.embedmongo:embedmongo-maven-plugin:0.1.13 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at com.github.joelittlejohn.embedmongo:embedmongo-maven-plugin:jar:0.1.13 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0 -> org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-8: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-8: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:pom:1.0-alpha-8 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
```

I do not think I am behind a proxy because I can access the URLs through my browser.

Comment: That you can access the URL in browser doesn't mean you are not behind a proxy. Browsers can be configured to pick the proxy automatically.

Comment: Well my maven build has been able to download artifacts from the central repo from all my other previous projects. How can I check if I'm behind a proxy?

Comment: Just check out the jar which have been tried to download are present in .m2 folder of windows current users folder for e.g. C:\Users\Ikshvaku , if no then delete the parent folder and rebuild the pom file. If jar is present then check file size is matched with actual size( file is corrupted ?)

Comment: It downloads the artifact partially. I get files with the extensions of .part, .lastUpdated, .lock

Comment: have you got .jar file in this folder? if no , delete this folder and rebuild.

Comment: well it's trying to download .pom files, and there is no .pom file, but when I tried rebuilding I get the same error.